# Transfers failing only with USDT tokens on faucet contract

Tags: contract-development, faucets, usdt

I have a [faucet](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x74c5f24bce70b22f2835abc621e5834d664cc626) to allow testing of different mainnet currencies. I've copy and pasted contracts of ERC20 tokens on the Mainnet and deployed them on Polygon Mumbai - [DAI](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/token/0x5eddd4de2ceb2c09c768e5dded49192b47e07cac) and [USDT (as PLAY)](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x22c4a36c09163e6334b99ebba1d2a639738ac28b).

The [faucet works fine](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xa1701f878f347c839ff9e64f80a439b49ae3422c567b4487bc4d577c5bcffac9) (when calling `request_topup`)for transfers of DAI tokens but will [error](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xa077bd62612bbe5443a9ca013926e08f22449e4ea286f914e5d1724b99d7b887) on the USDT(PLAY) ones when using the same calls. Here is [another example](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x4149d464c404c0625c6acd737ba26434f49fd5745c1fe952d75a4ef46ed5853d).

Is there something in the USDT contract that is stopping the transfer from going through? Ie. compiler version or a special flag? I'm at the loss because the errors are not much help. Any advice would be great.

[image]

The faucet code is here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20 {
  function transfer(address to,uint value) external returns(bool);
  function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns(uint);
}

contract Faucet {
  address public g__SiteAuthority;
  
  uint public g__SiteLimitAmount;
  
  bool public g__SiteLimitRequest;
  
  mapping(address => uint) public g__SiteRequests;
  
  constructor(uint limit) {
    g__SiteAuthority = msg.sender;
    g__SiteLimitAmount = limit;
  }
  
  event FaucetEvent(string event_type,string event_id,address sender,uint value);
  
  function limit_amount(uint limit) external {
    require(g__SiteAuthority == msg.sender,"Site Authority Only");
    g__SiteLimitAmount = limit;
  }
  
  function limit_requests(bool limit) external {
    require(g__SiteAuthority == msg.sender,"Site Authority Only");
    g__SiteLimitRequest = limit;
  }
  
  function request_balance_faucet(address erc20_address) external view returns(uint) {
    IERC20 erc20 = IERC20(erc20_address);
    return erc20.balanceOf(address(this));
  }
  
  function request_balance_caller(address erc20_address) external view returns(uint) {
    IERC20 erc20 = IERC20(erc20_address);
    return erc20.balanceOf(msg.sender);
  }
  
  function request_topup(uint amount,address erc20_address) external {
    if(g__SiteLimitRequest){
      uint prev = g__SiteRequests[msg.sender];
      require(
        (prev + 1 days) < block.timestamp,
        "Limited to 1 top up request per day"
      );
    }
    IERC20 erc20 = IERC20(erc20_address);
    uint balance = erc20.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    require(
      (balance + amount) < g__SiteLimitAmount,
      "Top up limit reached"
    );
    erc20.transfer(msg.sender,amount);
    g__SiteRequests[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
    emit FaucetEvent("topup","",msg.sender,amount);
  }
}
```